# Magento Admin User - Custom Attribute?

Tags: attributes, adminhtml, custom

In my Magento Admin Panel

System > Permissions > Users > choose any Users > **User Info**

I want to add an attribute that's a number called Calc_Code.
That the admin user can change in the backend.

Is it possible to add a custom attribute to an Admin user that they can change in the backend?

Comment: I believe this may have been answered previously here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25354/add-attribute-to-admin-user

Answer (score 2):

**Quick solution**

Only for your store open your **database** find the table **admin_user** click on it, after opening that table click on **structure** on top, on bottom click on **Go** button that add new column for your table.
add the name **Calc_Code** and type varchar than save it.

Then create this file: **app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/User/Edit/Tab/Main.php**

and add this code:

```
<?php class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

   protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = Mage::registry('permissions_user');

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('user_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Account Information')));

    if ($model->getUserId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('user_id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'user_id',
        ));
    } else {
        if (! $model->hasData('is_active')) {
            $model->setIsActive(1);
        }
    }

    $fieldset->addField('username', 'text', array(
        'name'  => 'username',
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Name'),
        'id'    => 'username',
        'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Name'),
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('firstname', 'text', array(
        'name'  => 'firstname',
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('First Name'),
        'id'    => 'firstname',
        'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('First Name'),
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('lastname', 'text', array(
        'name'  => 'lastname',
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Last Name'),
        'id'    => 'lastname',
        'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Last Name'),
        'required' => true,
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array(
        'name'  => 'email',
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Email'),
        'id'    => 'customer_email',
        'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Email'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-email',
        'required' => true,
    ));
// custom field
$fieldset->addField('calc_code', 'text', array(
        'name'  => 'calc_code',
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('calc_code'),
        'id'    => 'calc_code',
        'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('calc_code'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('current_password', 'obscure', array(
        'name'  => 'current_password',
        'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Current Admin Password'),
        'id'    => 'current_password',
        'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Current Admin Password'),
        'class' => 'input-text',
        'required' => true,
    ));

    if ($model->getUserId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('password', 'password', array(
            'name'  => 'new_password',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('New Password'),
            'id'    => 'new_pass',
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('New Password'),
            'class' => 'input-text validate-admin-password',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('confirmation', 'password', array(
            'name'  => 'password_confirmation',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password Confirmation'),
            'id'    => 'confirmation',
            'class' => 'input-text validate-cpassword',
        ));
    }
    else {
       $fieldset->addField('password', 'password', array(
            'name'  => 'password',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password'),
            'id'    => 'customer_pass',
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password'),
            'class' => 'input-text required-entry validate-admin-password',
            'required' => true,
        ));
       $fieldset->addField('confirmation', 'password', array(
            'name'  => 'password_confirmation',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password Confirmation'),
            'id'    => 'confirmation',
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password Confirmation'),
            'class' => 'input-text required-entry validate-cpassword',
            'required' => true,
        ));
    }

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId() != $model->getUserId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('is_active', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'is_active',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('This account is'),
            'id'        => 'is_active',
            'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Account Status'),
            'class'     => 'input-select',
            'style'        => 'width: 80px',
            'options'    => array('1' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Active'), '0' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Inactive')),
        ));
    }

    $fieldset->addField('user_roles', 'hidden', array(
        'name' => 'user_roles',
        'id'   => '_user_roles',
    ));

    $data = $model->getData();

    unset($data['password']);

    $form->setValues($data);

    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
}
?>
```

after clean the cache then check

Comment: I'm trying this out right now hang tight I'll upvote and choose as answer if it works

Comment: ya sure, and after creating Main.php add your field in between where you want to show like above example.

Comment: Use varchar for that

Comment: you are working on database you just have to go in admin_user table and just click on Go button and fill the form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48509/discussion-between-rajan-and-codingmagesheen).

Comment: so just put the 250 value in length

Comment: In the admin panel under system->my account can I also have the attribute display here?

Comment: No only for admin_user table

Comment: This adds the field to the form. But the data doesn't save when I click save.

Comment: Clear cache then check

Answer (score 1):

Thank You to @Rajan for helping me with:
I want to add an attribute that's a number called Calc_Code.
By directly adding it to the database Admin User's gained that attribute.

However I had to do some work to get the attribute saving in the backend, thus i'm posting my answer here for anyone that needs to do something similar.

I had to create a custom controller:

app/code/local/Sean/CustomCalcCode/controllers/Adminhtml/System/AccountController.php

```
    public function saveAction()
    {
        $userId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();
        $pwd    = null;

        $user = Mage::getModel("admin/user")->load($userId);

        $user->setId($userId)
            ->setUsername($this->getRequest()->getParam('username', false))
            ->setFirstname($this->getRequest()->getParam('firstname', false))
            ->setLastname($this->getRequest()->getParam('lastname', false))
            ->setEmail(strtolower($this->getRequest()->getParam('email', false)));

//IMPORTANT PART HERE
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $user->setData('calc_code', $post['Calc_Code']);
//IMPORTANT PART HERE

        if ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('new_password', false) ) {
            $user->setNewPassword($this->getRequest()->getParam('new_password', false));
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('password_confirmation', false)) {
            $user->setPasswordConfirmation($this->getRequest()->getParam('password_confirmation', false));
        }

        $result = $user->validate();
        if (is_array($result)) {
            foreach($result as $error) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($error);
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl("*/*/"));
            return;
        }
```

Also under:
app/code/local/Sean/CustomCalcCode/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_CustomCalcCode>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Sean_CustomCalcCode>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sean_customcalccode before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sean_CustomCalcCode_Adminhtml</sean_customcalccode>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

I learned from this experience you can't just add controllers through local file to replace mage core files.  You need to create the config.xml and manually save it like I did in my custom controller.

If any of you have any questions feel free to comment here or leave a question and PM me! I'll do my best to help you out.